# Unhandled exception in VS extension

Tags: visual-studio, vsix

I have tried creating a syntax highlighter for a custom file definition. I get an exception when its loaded. I have added the /log parameter to devenv to get a log.

```
335 ERROR System.Exception: Duplicate EditorFormatDefinition exports with identical NameAttribute metadata exist. Duplicate name attribute is COMMENT   Editor or Editor Extension 2010/08/18 06:47:56.726 
336 ERROR System.Exception: Duplicate EditorFormatDefinition exports with identical NameAttribute metadata exist. Duplicate name attribute is STRING   Editor or Editor Extension 2010/08/18 06:47:56.730 
337 ERROR System.Exception: Duplicate EditorFormatDefinition exports with identical NameAttribute metadata exist. Duplicate name attribute is COMMENT   Editor or Editor Extension 2010/08/18 06:47:57.046 
338 ERROR System.Exception: Duplicate EditorFormatDefinition exports with identical NameAttribute metadata exist. Duplicate name attribute is STRING   Editor or Editor Extension 2010/08/18 06:47:57.048 
339 ERROR System.Exception: Duplicate EditorFormatDefinition exports with identical NameAttribute metadata exist. Duplicate name attribute is COMMENT   Editor or Editor Extension 2010/08/18 06:47:57.078 
340 ERROR System.Exception: Duplicate EditorFormatDefinition exports with identical NameAttribute metadata exist. Duplicate name attribute is STRING
```

I cannot find any duplicates in my code. If needed code can be provided.

Best regards,
Michael

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have probably installed more than 1 plugin based on the same template/namespace/guid's.

Comment: Under Tool->"Extension Manager..." there are only one installed instance of the extension.

I can also add that I get some exceptions when debugging the extension, but nothing that refers to the add-in or the errors from the log.

Comment: You where almost right. I had some Classification Types that where the same as the ones already in VS. I renamed those, but the error still occurred. A rebuild did the trick.

Comment: Thank you. I had two conflicting extensions installed in Visual Studio 2010. David Egli's Multi Language Spell Checker v2.28 and EWSoftware's Visual Studio Spell Checker v2014.6.14.0. Disabling the Multi Language Spell Checker extension and restarting Visual Studio has fixed the problem.

Comment: In my case it was a problem described here - https://carstent.com/2017/06/22/visual-studio-2017-extension-load-error/ - duplicated PowerShell Tools