# In VS Extension project, Opening a file, I get this error [Duplicate EditorFormatDefinition exports with identical name attributes exist]

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

In Visual Studio extension project, Opening a file,i got the below popup. 
[image]

Navigate to the particular location i get the error information as

> System.ComponentModel.Composition.ImportCardinalityMismatchException:
>   Duplicate EditorFormatDefinition exports with identical name
>   attributes exist. Duplicate name is keyword
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception
>   exceptionObject)

How to resolve this issue?. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you deleted the .vs folder ?

Comment: No @JesúsNarváezTamés

Comment: Maybe you should try to delete it and check if the error persists.

Comment: I try that one but the folder automatically created@JesúsNarváezTamés

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Duplicate EditorFormatDefinition exports with identical name
>   attributes exist.

This could be similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509709/unhandled-exception-in-vs-extension). Normally the error message `Duplicate EditorFormatDefinition exports with identical name attributes exist` indicates you have **conflicting extensions installed** in your VS. More similar posts see here([one](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e8bff40b-55c3-4a09-8700-ad508fc56687/vs-2012-an-exception-has-been-encountered-this-may-be-caused-by-an-extension?forum=visualstudiogeneral) and [two](https://forums.asp.net/t/1883922.aspx?Issue+with+installing+Web+Tools+2012+2+Update+)).

**You can try steps below to resolve it:**

1.Go `Tools=>Extensions and Updates` to disable or uninstall all the third-party extensions there, and then close VS to make changes take effect. (Uninstalling them could be better to clean the environment)

2.Clean [VS components cache](https://github.com/Codealike/Codealike-KnowledgeBase/blob/master/clear-visual-studio-component-cache.md) and restart VS to check if the issue is resolved by creating a new VSIX project

If #1, #2 helps to resolve this issue, we can make sure it results from third-party extensions. Install the third-party extensions back one-by-one may help locate which extension causes this.

3.If the issue persists, maybe there's something broken with VS IDE. Update VS to latest version or run a VS repair to check if it makes any difference.

**In addition:** It's recommended that we update the VS2017 to latest 15.9.17, and update those extensions as well. This will make some help to avoid meeting this kind of issue.